# Spring AOP get modified parameter values

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I have two Spring aspects (let's call them *Aspect1* and *Aspect2*). *Aspect1* is executed before *Aspect2*, *Aspect1* is a logging aspect, *Aspect2* is an authentication aspect that will potentially update the value of one method parameter using the `ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(modifiedArgs)` (basically a `CustomAuthentication` object will be constructed if the authentication passed).  For logging purpose, I need to get the updated parameters inside *Aspect1* (the `CustomAuthentication` object before update is `null`, after update it will contain some actual data I need), I pray the `@AfterReturn` advice would do the work, and it didn't, so is there any way I can get this to work, or is it purely impossible?

EDIT 1: I should have stated that *Aspect1* has a lower order than *Aspect2*

Answer (score 0):

Your Aspect2 should work before Aspect1 so you need to define the order for your aspects.

From spring [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering):

> When two pieces of advice defined in different aspects both need to run at the same join point, unless you specify otherwise, the order of execution is undefined. You can control the order of execution by specifying precedence. This is done in the normal Spring way by either implementing the `org.springframework.core.Ordered` interface in the aspect class or annotating it with the `@Order` annotation. Given two aspects, the aspect returning the lower value from Ordered.getValue() (or the annotation value) has the higher precedence.

So first option is adding `@Order` annotation:

```
@Aspect
@Order(0)
public class Aspect2 {
    // your code
}

@Aspect
@Order(1)
public class Aspect1 {
    // your code
}
```

Second option is adding interface:

```
@Aspect
public class Aspect2 implements Ordered 
{
    public int getOrder() {
        return 0;
    }
    ...
}

@Aspect
public class Aspect1 implements Ordered 
{
    public int getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however, it is not what I wanted, I have stated that *Aspect1* is executed before *Aspect2*, so it does already have a lower order than *Aspect2*